# close the loop in .htaccess for redirecting all subfolders to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all subfolders to the root page using .htaccess. i.e. I'd like to redirect example.com/audio, example.com/video, example.com/images to example.com using below settings: However, I'd like to make it independent from the domain name. Hence, you don't see 'example.com' in my .htaccess setting.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)(.*)$  / [R]
```

When I test it, my browser gives me "redirected you too many times error message" error message. I have checked the apache logs and it shows that the request has been redirected so many times. I assume when htaccess redirects us to the root the above lines in .htaccess get run again and therefore it makes a loop. Is there any way I can force htaccess to redirect only those URL with subdirectory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=301]
```

With this rule, everything will be redirected to the root except the root itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" and it does not open the page. I copied and pasted what you have posted here.

Comment: Do you have other rules in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No, just what you have posted here.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional condition.