# redirect all directories and subdirectories to a specific directory using .htaccess

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect ***ALL*** directories and sub-directories within a domain to a certain directory on the same domain. For example, I want to redirect example.com/sub1 and example.com/sub1/sub2 to example.com/report.

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452583/close-the-loop-in-htaccess-for-redirecting-all-subfolders-to-root) to achieve my goal but, the guide in the answer does not help me to redirect all directories and sub-directories (e.g. /sub1 or /sub1/sub2) to /report. I also changed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/report
```

but it still does not help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch for this purpose :

```
RedirectMatch ^/((?!report).+)$ /report/
```

Comment: thanks starkeen, That does not help. Maybe because I am using nginx?